# Hover list of elements - Selenium Java WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover

Below is the scenario I am trying to test using Selenium WebDriver (2.53.1) and Java.

On a webpage, I have a list of stars. I want to hover over each of them, the stars get highlighted as we do a mouse hover. Then click on one of the stars. The css changes when each of the stars are hovered.

**Before hover**

```
  <div class="wh-rating-choices" style="display: none;">
        <div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
                                <a href="#">1</a>
                                <a href="#">2</a>
                                <a href="#">3</a>
                                <a href="#">4</a>
                                <a href="#">5</a>
                            <em>Your Rating: <span></span></em>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**After hover**

```
   <div class="wh-rating-choices" style="display: none;">
        <div class="wh-rating-choices-holder">
                                <a href="#" class="hover">1</a>
                                <a href="#" class="hover">2</a>
                                <a href="#" class="hover">3</a>
                                <a href="#" class="hover">4</a>
                                <a href="#" class="hover">5</a>
                            <em>Your Rating: <span>Excellent</span></em>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically, on successful hover, the class 'hover' gets added in the html/css.

**Code I have tried is as below.**

```
List<WebElement> allStars = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='hover']"));
System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<------List of all stars, size------------>>>>>>>>>>"+allStars.size());
for (WebElement e : allStars) {
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(e).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

As before hover, the class 'hover' is not added, the list of WebElements is always zero. Tried some of the options suggested on some selenium sites, but did not work. Please help, how to proceed on this one.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the top `<div>` element has `style="display: none;">`. Does it make sense to perform actions on elements that are not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested a solution, but it is very crude. It works, however.

Note: navigating directly to the fifth star (the element with text "5") didn't work for me. It seems you need to hover such that the rating holder box opens, and then hover to the fifth star so that you get all of them as class="hover".

This is what I did:

-- navigate to the element above ("Write a review") with Actions

-- move down (positive "y") in increments of 1 pixel

-- after every increment, test if the element with class "wh-rating-choices" contains string "block"

-- if it does, move to element with text "5" contained under the element with class "wh-rating-choices-holder"

I tested it in python, but here is what should work in Java:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
int inc = 0;
while (inc < 100) {
    WebElement top = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Write a Review')]"));
    action.moveToElement(top, 0, inc).contextClick().perform();
    Thread.sleep(200);
    a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'wh-rating-choices')]"));
    if (a.getAttribute("style").contains("block") {
        aa = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'wh-rating-choices-holder')]"));
        bb = aa.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(), '5')]"));
        action.moveToElement(bb).perform();
        break;
    }
    inc++;
}
System.out.println(bb.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
```

`Thread.sleep(200)` could be overkill, try something lower, like 50 or 20.

PS. It is possible you will need to close the pop-up first, the one that has `class="af-icon-cross"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `<a>` elements with `class="hover"` to be clickable and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement rating_holder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='wh-rating-choices']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", rating_holder)
List<WebElement> allStars = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='wh-rating-choices']/div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']//a")));
System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<------List of all stars, size------------>>>>>>>>>>"+allStars.size());
for (WebElement e : allStars) {
    if(e.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("5"))
    {
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(e).build().perform();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']//a[@class='hover']"))).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans, but it did not work. The hover class gets added to the html only when one of the stars are hovered over the mouse. That does not happen even when the wait is increased. At least one of the stars needs to be hovered for the hover class to be added.

Comment: @bhargavdesai What is your exact usecase? Which  do you want to hover to click ahead?

Comment: @bhargavdesai If you want to click on the 5  why do you want to iterate over all the ?

Comment: @bhargavdesai Why do you want to mouse hover over each  when you want to click only on the 5 ? That shouldn't be your usecase

Comment: @ DebanjanB: Sorry. may be my wordings are not correct. The usecase is -> hover over the stars,  make sure the stars inside get lit up when you hover over them, then click on the fifth star.

Comment: @bhargavdesai Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Sorry. The updated answer also did not work out. It timed out. - 'Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.xpath: //div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']//a'

Comment: @bhargavdesai Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @ DebanjanB: Sorry. Same result. The elements are not visible :(

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace executing the modified code block?

Comment: Are there multiple `<div>` with `class="wh-rating-choices"` on the page?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.xpath: //div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']//a

Comment: I have changed the _xpath_ a bit, take the updated code.

Comment: @DebanjanB @bhargav desai, guys I noticed the top-level `<div>` has `style="display: none;"`. This means that all the content of a div will not be visible for an end user, and actions like "click" will not actually work.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is that you are looking for `A` tags that already have the 'hover' class before you even hover. As you stated, the 'hover' class doesn't get added until *after* the hover occurs. So you would need to change your initial locator to *not* include the 'hover' class.

I prefer to use CSS selectors over XPath unless XPath is required (finding element by contained text or DOM traversal). You can do some googling for more info. Here's is tested code.

```
// find all A tags inside the containing DIV
List<WebElement> stars = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.wh-rating-choices-holder > a"));

// loop through each element and hover
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
for (WebElement e : stars)
{
    action.moveToElement(e).perform();
}

// after all the hovering is done, fetch the same elements but expect that they will now contain the 'hover' class
stars = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.wh-rating-choices-holder > a.hover"));

// Assert (TestNG) that there are 5 stars that were hovered
Assert.assertEquals(stars.size(), 5, "Verify 5 elements were hovered");

// click the 5th star
stars.get(4).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The assertion works but when i try to click, using the last step, an error is throw - 'element not interactable'.

Comment: And some times, the list is not populated. The assertion fails, as it cannot find a single element

Comment: I created a test page from the HTML you provided and it worked fine there. I'm not sure why it doesn't work on your actual page and until you provide a link to the page, you are going to have to work it out. You might try adding a `Thread.sleep(100)` inside the `for` loop. You might also need to add a wait before the assert. I'm not sure why the element is not interactable since it's an A tag and without the actual page, I would have to guess.

Comment: Tried with the Thread Sleep as well. Did not work. Can we please converse in a chat room ? Or is any other way we can connect?

Comment: Additional conversation really isn't going to help. What I/we need is a link to the page to work these out. This answer should be good enough to at least point you in the right direction. You will need to spend some time tweaking it to fit your situation.